# How To Prevent WordPress from automatically adding p tags on ONLY one page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have one page on my WordPress website that has some custom code on it (I cannot use Gutenberg blocks, only the classic Text/Visual editor). This code does not work because WordPress keeps adding p tags everywhere.

I tried adding this code to my functions.php, but it does not work. Can anyone help me to understand why this code doesn't work and how to stop WordPress from auto-generating p tags on just this 1 page?

```
if($post->ID == 352331) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is probably not working because $post is null or is not accessible. You may need to wrap the code within a hook and use the get_the_ID function to retrieve the ID of the current post.

```
add_action("after_setup_theme", function() {
   if(get_the_ID() == 352331) {
      remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
   }
}, 10);
```